# How to solve contradiction in statements

Tags: coq

I am solving a lemma ,I come across situation ,where I have to prove sub-lemma (true=false). contradiction does not work.How I can close this goal?
Another lemma, which is more or less same as above ,I have to prove sub_lemma
0=S n. Help me in closing these false statements.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you cannot actually prove these sub lemmas unless you have an assumption or hypothesis that proves False.  Say for example we have this proof:

```
Import Nat.

Theorem impossible :
  0 = 1.
Proof. Admitted.
```

As you can see, we attempt to prove something that is impossible at first.  0 is not equal to 1, so we have to admit the proof if we want the interpreter or compiler to continue.
In contrast, we have a proof that *appears* to be your solution problem:

```
Theorem possible1 :
  False ->
  0 = 1.
Proof.
  intro H.
  exfalso.
  apply H.
Qed.
```

We have the same proof, but we assume `False` at first.  `False` is a member of the type `Prop` (Proposition), which is at the core of how Coq decides if something is True.  If you can evaluate a set of `Prop`s to a `True` state, then you have solved the proof (this is vastly oversimplified, I'm just trying to get the idea across).
However, if we assume `False` as a hypothesis, we have assumed the inverse of `True` is `True`.  If that's the case, then anything that should be considered improvable is now provable.  If we assume `False`, we can prove anything.
In this first example though, we coerce `0 = 1` into `False` with `exfalso`.  Then, as H is exactly our goal, we can apply H (or use the `assumption` tactic).

```
Theorem possible2 :
  False ->
  0 = 1.
Proof.
  intro H.
  inversion H.
Qed.
```

Inversion is another useful tactic that can be used here.  It has *many* other useful applications, but it can be used as a shorthand to end your goal given a `False` assumption.  If you apply inversion to the false hypothesis, it effectively does the same thing as `possible1` and completes the goal for you.  It recognizes that assuming `False` means you can prove anything.

Finally, we have the ability to delay a part of a proof:

```
Theorem delay:
  forall (n : nat),
  n = S n.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
  - admit.
  - rewrite <- IHn.
    apply IHn.
  (* Can't prove base case *)
Admitted.
```

Recall from `impossible` that we had to use the `Admitted` keyword to end the proof.  We have to use `Admitted` because it's not possible to reach a state where all goals are satisfied, and therefore we can't exit the proof state using `Qed`.
However, the `admit` tactic will let you delay proving something until later.  If you think of your goals as two separate tasks on their own sheets of paper stacked on each other, you can use `admit` to move the top sheet below and divert it until later.  You will have to come back to that diverted sub-lemma before you can exit the proof though, or use `Admitted` again.
The compiler `CoqC` is not as helpful as the IDE for proving theorems in this way, so if you can use it I highly recommend.  (My current project involves Extraction, which I think requires the compiler and is not supported by the IDE.  If someone comments otherwise, I'll delete this footnote)

Comment: During induction I come across a situation,Where first case is (true),I have proved it.But I don't know how to prove second case (false).Here is an example Theorem length_zero_true :forall (l:list nat),
(length l - length l =? 0) = true.
Proof.
intros. induction (length l).
simpl. auto.
simpl. apply IHn.
Qed.

Theorem length_zero_false :forall (l:list nat),
(length l - length l =? 0) = false.
Proof.
intros. induction (length l).
simpl. auto.
simpl.
Qed. Now I have true =false in sub lemma.

Comment: In hypothesis, I have false=false.In sub lemma I want to prove true=false

Comment: In your first comment, with proof "length_zero_false", that simply isn't provable.  You proved the converse (that it was true) in "length_zero_true", so logically the latter shouldn't be possible.
In "length_zero_false", there is no contradictory hypothesis (H: true=false, Contra: False, etc.) so it's not provable.  Are you sure you have the right definition for your theorems?

Comment: Everything that appears in the upper right box on the IDE is considered a hypothesis.  Example:
`Theorem E1: P .
Proof... 
(* Your goal here is to prove P *)

Theorem E2: P -> Q.
Proof...
(* Your goal is to prove Q assuming P as a hypothesis *)`

Comment: I think you should change the first word in your answer from "Unfortunately" to "Fortunately". :-)

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot more sense actually.  Shows how Coq is intentionally designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities: either (1) your initial statement was already not provable, or (2) you took a turn in the middle of your proof, which leads you to a new sub-goal that is not provable, or (3) there is a combination of hypotheses in your goal that is contradictory, but neither you nor the basic `contradiction` tactic can see that this is contradictory.  For more help, we would need to see the full attempt.